# Multiple objects in a ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

Can we set more than one object in a `ThreadLocal` ?

Comment: not on the same thread, you cant :-)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do and what problems you're experiencing?

Comment: Just for academic purpose . I wanted to know if we can set more than one object in ThreadLocal so that we can retrieve it later . I didn't want to use Map for that purpose !

Comment: You can see in the Javadoc that set() only sets one object and get() only gets one objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A thread local is a local variable of the current thread; so each thread gets exactly one value. But the value can be an instance, so you can put a map in there, for example or a custom type which collects all the values that you want.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that using any kind of Collection in a ThreadLocal could exacerbate memory leaks/usage associated with ThreadLocals

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple `ThreadLocal` and you can have an object in it which contains multiple objects.

e.g.

```
final ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> localProperties = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>() {
     public Map<String, String> initialValue() {
           return new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
     }
});
```

Comment: With this approach, it's important to cognizant keep in mind that using any kind of Collection in a ThreadLocal could exacerbate memory leaks/usage associated with ThreadLocals

Comment: Hi @Peter Does this mean that multiple thread will have same instance of threadLocal ( because its static) in this case.

Comment: @Tarun Yes, the ThreadLocal is a key into a Map for each thread. When you call get() it looks up the map for the Thread.currentThread() for the reference for that thread

Answer (score 1):

We can create multiple ThreadLocal objects in a single Thread and access it using a particular ThreadLocal object's `get()` method.

Actually a ThreadLocal has a static inner class called ThreadLocalMap and its a customized hashmap, where key in this customized map is ThreadLocal object and value is value to be stored.

Every thread holds the reference of this threadLocalMap object.

Comment: Example provided in the link is not the right usage of threadlocal